# Python How to count the amount of times something happens in an hour per day per week from a CSV that is a week long?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a CSV with data that looks like:

```
Machine Name Timestamp
Washer #25   2021-08-22 06:07:21
Washer #2    2021-08-22 06:35:15
Dryer #34    2021-08-22 17:05:55
...          ...
Dryer #29    2021-08-28 05:17:12
```

The CSV itself spans a week, Sunday to Saturday and is over 1300 rows long. I am trying to count how many times machines are used per hour per day. So in the above example my output would look like

```
2021-08-22: 0600, Machine Count: 2
2021-08-22: 1700, Machine Count: 1
2021-08-23: 0500, Machine Count: 1
```

It uses military hours so 0000-2359

Currently I am using Pandas, and have opened and read my CSV and grabbed the hour and date out of the Timestamp column. I re-added the hour as a new column at the end of the dataframe, so a timestamp of 09:45:16 would be added in as 9. This was done while I was experimenting and can be taken out.
Current code is:

```
csv = PATHTOCSV
df = pd.read_csv(csv)

hourHolder = (pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.hour)
dateHolder = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.date
df['Hour'] = hourHolder

fullDictionary = df.to_dict('Records')
```

I have tried various methods using loops and trying to query the data directly using `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='H')).count()`

However that gives an error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
> PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor the datetime column to the hour, groupby and count.

```
s = """Machine Name,Timestamp
Washer #25,2021-08-22 06:07:21
Washer #2,2021-08-22 06:35:15
Dryer #34,2021-08-22 17:05:55
Dryer #29,2021-08-28 05:17:12"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h'))['Machine Name'].count()

Timestamp
2021-08-22 06:00:00    2
2021-08-22 17:00:00    1
2021-08-28 05:00:00    1
Name: Machine Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @KozerH using `io.StringIO` is how I read the sample data. You would use whatever method you are currently using to create the original dataframe

Comment: Ok this works. I want to apologize if the formatting of my comment is terrible, don't have a lot of experience writing comments on stackoverflow. 

I needed to take the StringIO(csv) out of my read_csv(csv) line to get it to work. My ending code looks like


`df = pd.read_csv(csv)

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

print(df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h'))['Machine Name'].count())`

Also sorry, my comment formatting was terrible and I deleted my original comment.